# Pick a unique random subset from a set of unique values

Tags: c++, stl, random

C++. Visual Studio 2010.

I have a `std::vector` V of N unique elements (**heavy** structs). How can efficiently pick M random, unique, elements from it?

E.g. V contains 10 elements: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } and I pick three...

- 4, 0, 9
- 0, 7, 8
- But NOT this: 0, 5, 5 <--- not unique!

STL is preferred. So, something like this?

```
std::minstd_rand gen; // linear congruential engine??
std::uniform_int<int> unif(0, v.size() - 1);
gen.seed((unsigned int)time(NULL));

// ...?

// Or is there a good solution using std::random_shuffle for heavy objects?
```

Comment: your definition of 'unique' is commonly referred to as '(drawing) without replacement'

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a **random permutation** of the range `0, 1, ..., N - 1` and pick the first `M` of them; use those as *indices* into your original vector.

A random permutation is easily made with the standard library by using `std::iota` together with `std::random_shuffle`:

```
std::vector<Heavy> v; // given

std::vector<unsigned int> indices(V.size());
std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
std::random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end());

// use V[indices[0]], V[indices[1]], ..., V[indices[M-1]]
```

You can supply [`random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) with a random number generator of your choice; check the docu­men­tation for details.

Comment: Damn, that was fast! I can accept the answer in 8 minutes, so I get some time to test it :)

Comment: **NOTE!** `std::random_suffle` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17. Instead, use `std::shuffle` with C++11 and later. This function plays better with the much improved RNG functionality in C++11.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the time, the method provided by Kerrek is sufficient.  But if N is very large, and M is orders of magnitude smaller, the following method may be preferred.

Create a set of unsigned integers, and add random numbers to it in the range [0,N-1] until the size of the set is M.  Then use the elements at those indexes.

```
std::set<unsigned int> indices;
while (indices.size() < M)
    indices.insert(RandInt(0,N-1));
```

Comment: that does not guarantee the required 'uniqueness' (i.e. a value can appear more than once in `indices`)

Comment: @AndreHolzner: Yes, it does guarantee uniqueness.  No a value cannot appear more than once in `indices`.  `std::set` takes care of that.  If you try to insert a duplicate, it will not go in, and the size of the set will remain unchanged.

Comment: this is inefficient if M is very close to N. e.g. running this with M=N=1000 should give horrible results.

Comment: @kritzikratzi: Obviously. Does the first paragraph not make clear under which conditions this method would be preferable?

Comment: ha, you're absolutely right. you're stating it quite clearly... glad i didn't downvote :)

Comment: In C++11, std::unordered_set is preferred for performance as order is not important

Comment: If the `RandInt` method returns a truly random number, the loop might get stuck. The same goes for a flawed randum number. I would certainly never use this kind of loops in my code.

Comment: @l33t: All sorts of absurdly unlikely events are possible. I would suggest not planning your life (or your code) around such possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted it to be efficient, I think you can get an amortised `O(M)`, assuming you have to perform that operation a lot of times. However, this approach is not reentrant.

First of all create a local (i.e. `static`) vector of `std::vector<...>::size_type` (i.e. `unsigned` will do) values.

If you enter your function, resize the vector to match `N` and fill it with values from the old size to `N-1`:

```
static std::vector<unsigned> indices;
if (indices.size() < N) {
  indices.reserve(N);
  for (unsigned i = indices.size(); i < N; i++) {
    indices.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

Then, randomly pick `M` unique numbers from that vector:

```
std::vector<unsigned> result;
result.reserver(M);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < M; i++) {
  unsigned const r = getRandomNumber(0,N-i); // random number < N-i
  result.push_back(indices[r]);
  indices[r] = indices[N-i-1];
  indices[N-i-1] = r;
}
```

Now, your result is sitting in the `result` vector.

However, you still have to repair your changes to `indices` for the next run, so that `indices` is monotonic again:

```
for (unsigned i = N-M; i < N; i++) {
  // restore previously changed values
  indices[indices[i]] = indices[i];
  indices[i] = i;
}
```

But this approach is only useful, if you have to run that algorithm a lot and `N` doesn't grow so big that you cannot live with `indices` eating up RAM all the the time.