# Draw n random elements (w/o replacment) from an stl container

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, random, stl-algorithm

More or less the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650991/pick-a-unique-random-subset-from-a-set-of-unique-values) but where the container to select from is as general as possible (i.e. only a [Forward Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardContainer.html) or maybe even just a simple [Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html)) in particulate it should not be assumed the container has a .size() and walking it twice (once to count the size and again to get the result set) is not acceptable.

I have a one solution that's just a bit more complex and with a few more dependencies than I'd like so I'm hoping for something in the 3-5 lines range.

Comment: Does it have a `.begin()` and an `.end()`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I think all stl containers have that.

Comment: Then `size_t size = cont.end() - cont.begin();`

Comment: @H2CO3: doesn't work for std::map http://ideone.com/jknTEk or std::set http://ideone.com/QDjZPw

Answer (score 2):

I assume by 'random elements' you mean elements distributed evenly.

Since you have no knowledge of the sequence's length, and you can't calculate it beforehand, you have to build your random sequence gradually. So let's do that, and hope the probabilities we use all add up nicely so we end up with what we wanted in the first place.

We'll do this in two steps. First, decide which of the sequence numbers are drawn, and then we can choose a random order for them, if we need to (it wasn't clear from the question). And I'll call your N 'K', because it's easier for me.

First we create a K element array, to hold the K drawn elements. We go over the first K elements of the sequence and copy them to the array. If the sequence doesn't have K elements, we say "No can do".

Now we know we have K random elements from a K-size sequence. If we are at the end of the sequence, we're done. If not, we know we have a K+1 size sequence. There are two options here, either the K+1'th item is selected, or it doesn't.

What are is the probability of the K+1'th item to be selected? I find it easier to calculate the probability the K+1'th item is *not* selected. There are (K+1 over K) ways to choose K elements from K+1, and only (K over K) ways to choose K elements if the K+1's element doesn't appear. So (K over K) / (K+1 over K) is the probability of the K+1'th item not being selected.

So, choose a random number between 0 and 1, if it's less than 1/(K+1) the K+1'th element doesn't appear in the sequence. If the random number is more than that, the K+1'th element does appear in the sequence. Choose a random element between 1 and K, and replace it with the K+1'th element.

Now we move to the next item, the K+2'th item. And we do the same thing again. The probability of the K+2'th item to not appear in the sequence is (K+1 over K) / (K+2 over K).

Do that until the sequence is exhausted. Then you have a list of K elements randomly chosen from the sequence.

Note that they are not ordered randomly (at least not for short sequences), so you may want to choose a random K-size permutation for that.

Disclaimer: Probability is a bitch, and although this seems right to me, there's a chance I missed something and the end result will not be evenly distributed. Others will tell pretty quickly.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, zmbq I think that would work. OTOH I was hoping for something simpler, like that already wrapped in a nice function.

Comment: I was sure someone already came up with this and gave it a catchy name. I just couldn't find it. You can wrap it in a nice function - it's really not that bad. @David Eisenstat's link has the entire algorithm in pseudo code.