# How can I get multiple set of 4 arrays with the elements from 2 other arrays with no elements that be in the same array twice

Tags: php, algorithm

```
//2 initial arrays
var $m = ["m1","m2","m3","m4","m5","m6","m7","m8"];
var $f = ["f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","f6","f7","f8"];
```

Each array from the 4 arrays set must contain 2 elements from the array $m and 2 elements from the array $f

```
//first set of 4 arrays
var $group1a = ["m1", "m2", "f1", "f2"];
var $group2a = ["m3", "m4", "f3", "f4"];
var $group3a = ["m5", "m6", "f5", "f6"];
var $group4a = ["m7", "m8", "f7", "f8"];
```

I need to create few more set of 4 arrays with no elements that be in the same array twice.
for example

```
var $group1b = ["m1", "m3", "f6", "f7"]; // this is correct.
var $group1b = ["m1", "m3", "f1", "f4"]; // this is incorrect because m1 and f1 be in the same array again.

$group1b = ["m1", "m2", "f3", "f6"];// is incorrect because m1 and m2 already be together in $gorup1a. 
$group1b = ["m1", "m3", "f5", "f6"];// is incorrect because f5 and f6 already be together in $group3a
$group2b = ["m2", "m4", "f1", "f2"]; // is incorrect because f1 and f2 already be together in $group1a
```

I'm thinking of creating variables for each element in the 2 initial array to keep track of what elements they were group with.

Comment: I think you need to give more detail of the logic behind which elements should be in your result arrays. Should `$group1b` contain `["m2", "m4", "f1", "f2"]`? How are you going about filling these arrays?

Comment: Each array from the 4 arrays set must contain 2 elements from the array $m and 2 elements from the array $f. $group1b = ["m1", "m2", "f3", "f6"]; is incorrect because m1 and m2 already be together in $gorup1a. same goes for $group1b = ["m1", "m3", "f5", "f6"]; f5 and f6 already be together in $group3a

Comment: oh yea sorry that is inccorect. I'll edit the post sorry

Comment: Do you know anything about the lengths of `$m` and `$f`?

Comment: $m and $f length can be 4,8,12,16... I'm just trying to make it work with 8 now

Comment: So, the result arrays are supposed to be randomly chosen from the initial arrays as long as they meet the "not already together in previous groups" criteria?

Comment: yes. not in the same group twice and the array must contain 2 elements from $f and 2 elements from $m

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify the random aspect. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: This is not work related or anything. I'm in a beach volleyball group and we run co-ed tournaments sometime where we mix the girls and the guys. I'm just trying to help the organizer to have easier time in making the schedule where no one has to play against the same person twice. I thought it was gonna be a piece of cake but It's not lol.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to [Pick a unique random subset from a set of unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650991/pick-a-unique-random-subset-from-a-set-of-unique-values), except that the set of values in this problem are the pairs ([m1, f1], [m2, f2], ...) and the sets need to be unique. So, you need to first select a unique set with unique values, then verify that you haven't already used that set.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is closely related to some [very difficult mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design). Here's an optimal explicit construction for 8 and 8 based on the [finite affine plane of order 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry#Finite_affine_and_projective_planes) with coordinates in (**Z**/2)[x]/(1 + x + x<sup>2</sup>), using `$m = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]` and `$f = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]`.

- <strike>`ABCD, EFGH, abcd, efgh`</strike>
- `AEae, BFbf, CGcg, DHdh`
- `AFch, BEdg, CHaf, DGbe`
- `AGdf, BHce, CEbh, DFag`
- `AHbg, BGah, CFde, DEcf`

I'm sorry to say that it's not clear at all how to generalize this solution. That's frequently the situation with block designs as well.

Here's the affine plane, for reference.

```
      0   1   x  1+x
     ---------------
 0  | A   B   C   D
 1  | E   F   G   H
 x  | a   b   c   d
1+x | e   f   g   h
```

Comment: Did you follow a formula to calculate this result? Am I supposed to use this (Z/2)[x]/(1 + x + x2) to calculate the coords?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no simple algorithm for this, I have to use brute force method to check for duplicate by looping through all previous sub arrays when a new array is created. So far, it works.