# Random indices in Point cloud

Tags: c++11, point-clouds

I am trying to find random indices for selecting some points in point cloud. 
Following is the code. However, even after using srand() I am getting same number all three times. Can someone please help, regarding this?

```
/* find three points randomly */ 
for (long i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
{
   srand (time(NULL));
   cout <<"\nRandom index" << (rand() % points.size() + 1); 
}
```

Comment: read carefully about [srand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) you'll get what wrong with your code.

Comment: Yup...$srand()$ has to be called once..outside the loop...thanks :)

Comment: There are some caveats with rand() that you should be aware of. Most importantly, the range of rand() is often very limited and can be as low as [0, 32767], which means you'll only ever select 3 points from the first 32767 points and point clouds tend to be much larger than that. There are better random number generators available in C++11, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random
Another caveat is, that you're not preventing the same number being chosen twice, which may or may not be a problem. You could create unique indices like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651058/913630

Comment: Thanks @Markus for the hidden details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeding your random generator with the same time, once each loop iteration.

Instead seed it once at the start:

```
/* find three points randomly */ 
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
  cout <<"\nRandom index" << (rand() % points.size() + 1); 
}
```

You also don't need to use `long` for a loop of three steps :)